Should I cite 200 webpages?
For my paper I am getting quarterly data on company earnings from their 10-Q reports. I am scraping together about 200 of these reports.
Am I supposed to cite all 200 of these, or I can just say the reports can be found using SEC EDGAR and cite it once? I'm using APA, if it matters.

Are the 200 reports all the reports on the site and does the site ever add new ones?

Its not all of them, and new ones are constantly added. @MisterMiyagi

I think this is a job for an appendix and not for citations.
Add an appendix (or in case this is too much for a journal paper, an online supplement) where you list the 200 companies/data sources in full.  Papers and theses are permanent publications, but websites change regularly, so listing to an external website is not good enough.  Although the internet archive should be permanent, it is better to keep the important information in one place.

An online only supplement is dangerous unless someone can guarantee its maintenance. And, being a website itself, it is subject to change.

@Buffy That's the publisher's job.  I think many journals are online-only anyway these days.  How the permanence of online resources is guaranteed is a different question.

The context here is a thesis, however.

@Buffy I didn't see that from the question.  For a thesis I would certainly include it in the thesis and not in an online supplement.  I've edited my answer to cover both cases.

Paper, it's a supplement or data file, but you put as much as you can in a thesis so it looks more impressive on the shelf.

If that single link points to a page/site that is updated, then it would be improper to link to only it. You might be required to link to each site that you refer to in the paper, especially for each company explicitly named, and, importantly, stating the date on which you accessed the data. If you can point to a completely stable site, like the internet archive, then the date isn't necessary, but otherwise it is, as content changes.
However, I can think of an exception. If you don't name the companies specifically, and if you have explicit permission from them to use their data "anonymously", then you can, perhaps, treat the data as a data-set and refer to it generically without citing each "data point". I'm using the analogy of a data set from a set of human subjects who aren't named in a work, but who have given permission for their data to be used. Permission can come from a general license, of course or an accepted understanding that the data is public. Note that I'm guessing a bit here and you could discuss this with your advisor, who knows the field and its conventions.
In a thesis, though, having a lot of references probably isn't a problem.

I think gerrit's answer is better; references/citation is the wrong tool for this use case. It's important that OP describe their methodology in a reproducible way, an appendix listing the data sources would be one good option, but I don't think intermingling with the other references is the way to go.

@BryanKrause, you said intermingling, I didn't.

Well, technically these are companies listed on the US stock market, so they are required by law to publish their quarterly earnings,  the SEC website collects these quarterly reports. None of the reports change after publication, I should have clarified it better, my bad. From getting the data from these sources, I will create the dataset which I explain and use in methodology. @BryanKrause I thought appendix is only for extra tables and charts, but I could put this there

@Buffy I think the presumption is that references all go together, and OP is talking about them with a citation style that they're presumably using for the rest of the paper; you haven't said anything about keeping them separate, you've discussed them as references and talked about things like "having a lot of references probably isn't a problem" in a thesis, which again seems to suggest that they're all together.

@JohnFire "Appendix" is a rather general term, you might not have them in a section actually labeled "Appendix". It's becoming more common in many fields to expect the entire data used to be provided in some form with the paper, perhaps deposited in some repository. If there's enough information in the data set to indicate where the data are coming from, that's likely also sufficient. The purpose of citations are to point people to where you've gotten your ideas. The purpose of telling people where you've gotten your data is a little different and likely need not follow a citation style.

@BryanKrause, note that APA style citation permits both footnotes and endnotes. It does not require "intermingling".

If you are proposing including this information in a footnote or endnote, I would suggest being explicit about that in your answer, but I would still downvote that suggestion because I do not think those are the best places or format for this information.

Does your institution have some kind of system for persistent research data storage? It sounds like you have compiled an original dataset by scraping this website. Your institution may have infrastructure in place for preserving research datasets. You would then cite your own dataset in your paper.

I found two sources offering advice on these types of citations:

Harvard Business School makes available on one of its resources web pages a document titled "HBS Citation Guide: 2024–25 Academic Year". This guide includes a section titled "Citations of Commercial Databases" (page 43). It includes the following guideline:


URLs are optional in database citations. If you include a URL, use only the briefest form which points to the main page of the database.


SEC EDGAR is a government database, not a commercial database, so I can't say for sure this guideline applies, but the distinction between commercial and non-commercial databases does not seem that important to me. The HBS Citation Guide also has a section titled "Government Documents" (pages 22-25). I don't see anything there pertaining to databases specifically, but I didn't look very carefully.
You may also want to consider whether the HBS citation guidelines, which I imagine are tailored to academics working in the areas of business, management and related disciplines, are relevant for the specific discipline you are publishing in.

By contrast, this library research guide from Washtenaw Community College does have guidance that suggests including the URLs for each downloaded report:

Annual Report or SEC Filing (10-K) from the SEC Edgar Database:
"Title of SEC Filing or Annual Report." Name of Website. Publisher, Date of Publication, URL, DOI,
or permalink.
"Nike, Inc. Form 10-K for Fiscal Year Ended May 31, 2016." EDGAR. Securities and Exchange
Commission, 2016, https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/320187/000032018716000336/nke-5312016x10k.htm



